# Android: Back to previous app issue

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-finish

In my application, just call it `mApp`, I have `mHome` and `mView` activity. `mHome` is for user profile, settings etc. `mView` can be called by `3rd part App1` for view decrypt files. mView will decrypt files and called specific App(PDF Reader or any reader) to view plain file.

So, the work flow is:

> 3rd part App1 ---> mView Activity (startActivityForResult)---> PDF Reader.

When the user goes back from PDF Reader, i just finish `mView` in `onActivityResult`, and it goes back to `3rd part App1` perfectly.(The user won't see `mView` screen when turned back).

But issue came from following work flow:

> open mApp ---> press home button ---> 3rd part App1 ---> mView Activity ---> PDF Reader.

When user returned from PDF Reader, it just goes back to `mHome` screen.
Anything i missed? I have tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

Thanks for your time.

**Append(`code in mView`):**

```
private void responseView(Uri uri) {
    String mime = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mime);
    // Grant temporary read permission to the content URI
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
    if (isIntentSafe) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, ZConstants.REQUEST_VIEW_FILE);
    } else {
        ToastUtil.showToast(this, getString(R.string.no_available_app_hint), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
 }


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {   
     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
     finish();
}
```

**Append(Mainfest):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zz.mapp"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.zz.mapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

    <activity
        android:name="com.zz.mapp.ui.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.zz.mapp.ui.ViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="mapp.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="mapp.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Update:**

I can solve above problem by adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to mView activity, it works perfectly without starting another activity in mView, for instance, `Sign In or Sign Up`. So, some more work should i do to get `starting another activity` work.

Comment: @Libin, mainfest posted. thx

Comment: What is `App1`? What is `press home`? is the phone's home button or the `mHome` activity?

Comment: @rubenlop88, thanks for point out the confusion thing, post updated.

Comment: @SwAinsun Much clearer now.